# db.collection.find returns zero docs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongojs

Newbie question here - just starting out with Express, Node and Mongojs.

I've created a tiny db in Mongod called 'users' and if I do:

```
db.users.find()
```

from the Mongo shell, I get an array of docs returned.

I've set up app.js in Express which renders a page fine.
Also package.json has:

```
"mongojs": "^2.4.1"
```

defined in the dependencies section.

I've required mongojs at the top of app.js and defined a var db:

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('custapp', ['users']);
```

When I do a db.users.find in my Express code, it returns an empty docs result:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  db.users.find(function(err, docs){
    console.log(docs);
  })
})
```

Simple compassionate answers for a complete newbie please!
I know nothing :-)

Comment: Are you connecting to a wrong database?

Comment: first of all, did you try to `console.log` the `err` variable?

Comment: console.log(err) give me "null" in the console

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally worked out the answer to this. My newbie bad!

When I set up the mongod db I called it "customerapp" and in the app.js connection string I called it "custapp".

I discovered the db.getName() function to see what I had called it at setup time.